# C++ Error: "Expression must have integral or enum type"

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error *"Expression must have integral or enum type"* on the `switch` statement of my (incomplete) function below. I've stared at it for a while and can't figure out what the matter is. Any insight greatly appreciated.

```
std::string CWDriver::eval_input(std::string expr)
{
    std::vector<std::string> params(split_string(expr, " "));
    std::string output("");
    if (params.size() == 0)
    {
        output = "Input cannot be empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        switch (params[0])
        {
            case "d":

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's confusing about it? The error tells you what's going on. Where did you read that you can `switch` on a `std::string`?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the point that a string is not an integral type?

Comment: In C/C++, you can't switch on strings or other composite types.

Comment: Are you intending to switch on params[0][0]? Ie. the char 'd'?

Answer (score 7):

The error is clear. You can only use *integral* types (`integer`, `enum`, `char` etc. which are *convertible* to `integral` value), or any *expression* that evaluates to an integral type in `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`params[0]` has type of `std::string`. You can't use `std::string` type (which is not integral) as a `switch` parameter. If you are confident strings are not empty use `switch (param[0][0])` and `case 'd'`. But in this case you will be able to switch over one-character strings only. If you need to switch over longer strings you need to use the sequence of `if-else if-else if-...`.